# Bootstrap carousel doesn't load

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 and i have a problem with my carousel.
It doesn't slide auto. But if i click on right or left it works and auto slide work too.

my code:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height:344px;">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      </ol>

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <img src="assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="...">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">    
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="assets/img/img2.jpg" alt="...">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Did you include bootstrap.js in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Acutually this works auto, you just have to wait until the first slide will move out. If you want to manage the interval you can use jQuery as in the provided example (that starts from your code):

```js
 var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
  $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({ interval: 5000, cycle: true });
  });
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height:344px;">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/img/img2.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to intialize the carousel with JavaScript.

Add this to your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('carousel-example-generic').carousel({
        interval: 2000
 })

});
</script>
```